# Swift - Animate MPVolumeView Slider Thumb

Tags: xcode, swift, mpvolumeview

When a user changes the volume using the hardware volume buttons, I want my MPVolumeView Slider Thumb to animate itself to the position. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView mainVolumeSlider

```
        mainVolumeSlider.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        let myVolumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: mainVolumeSlider.bounds)
        mainVolumeSlider.addSubview(myVolumeView)
```